# how to find the number of points of intersection of $y=\sin(x)^{\sec(x)}$ and $y=\cos(x)^{\csc(x)} \text{ for } x ∈ (0,π/2)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Or in a different format,

$$\sin(x)^{\sec(x)}=\cos(x)^{\csc(x)}$$

I was thinking, the way to solve this is LHS->increasing function, and RHS->decreasing in given domain so the graph would intersect at just one location, but I'm not sure

Comment: Well, LHS is not a _strictly_ increasing function. Try plotting it out. In the given range, the two curves do, in fact, have only $1$ point of intersection at $x = \dfrac\pi4$.

Comment: how do i plot this curve?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7oykhqvvzq

Comment: There are many services (online) and tools, as well as software for plotting. I will recommend GeoGebra, it is FREE...

Comment: no, like without a graphing calculator, this is a question that had come in one of our exams, I used my logic and guessed the ans as 1, but i just wanted to know if my methods right. No calculators allowed in the exam btw

Comment: In the "different format", the two curves *are* increasing and decreasing, so your solution works in that form.